# Train and Test with 'one class classifier' using Weka

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka

Suppose I have the following train-set:

```
f1,f2,f3,     label
1,2,3,          0
1.2,2.3,3.3,    0
1.25,2.25,3.25, 0
```

and I want to get the classification for the following test-set:

```
f1,f2,f3,     label
6,7,8,          ?
1.1,2.1,3.1,    ?
9,10,11,        ?
```

When I'm using Weka and 'One class classifier', first I load the train-set and  classify using *use training set* option in the test options, after that I choose the *supplied test set* option and load the above test set.The problem is that I get the same classification for all the test-set instances and I get a warning that the *train and test set are not compatible, do you want to wrap with inputMappedClassifier?*. The above are just a simple examples, I got these problems also with a huge anomaly injected dataset.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: OneClassClassifier is used when there are several classes in the dataset, but you'd like to make it a binary classification problem (this class or outlier). see this http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.packages/oneClassClassifier/weka/classifiers/meta/OneClassClassifier.html.  if there is only class in the dataset, use SVM. see this https://weka.wikispaces.com/LibSVM and the example for single class dataset

Answer (score 0):

I think, Since you are performing oneClassClassification, your test data should be (assumption here is all the test data rows are not outliers):

```
f1,f2,f3,     label
6,7,8,          0
1.1,2.1,3.1,    0
9,10,11,        0
```

and if you enable predictions on test data, you may get:

=== Predictions on test set ===

```
inst#     actual  predicted error prediction
   1     1:true     1:true       1 
   2     1:true          ?       ? 
   3     1:true     1:true       1:true
```

which means in test data:
a) Instance 1 is not outlier
**b) Instance 2 is outlier**
c) Instance 3 is not outlier